# Calculation using javascript in drupal 6

Tags: javascript, drupal

Hi everyone i am new to drupal i am developing a module where i need a calculation using java scrip or jquery but i dont no how to implement .js files or how to write a javascript in drupal can anyone pls provide me a releated links or any help on this thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add javascript to your module using [drupal_add_js](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/6) and for adding to Page template use normal way (using script tag)

Remember that javascript client side script and preferred for preprocessing like form validation

EDIT:

[tutorial](http://www.packtpub.com/article/working-with-javascript-in-drupal6-part1) ,
[samples](http://drupal.org/node/84893)

Comment: can anyone pls provide me a links were i can find samples it will be very help full to me

Comment: sure. Check the link in my answer